# cannot get jnius to work with chaquopy/android studio

Tags: python, android-studio, openai-api, chaquopy

I am making a simple python script that utilizes openai and jnius(or as it's now known 'pyjnius) libraries with the intention of integrating with android studio.
I have the mainactivity.xml and everything working perfectly, internet access setup in the manifest etc.
My only issue is when asking ChatGPT a question (in the emulator while running the app) I am getting a response in the app UI that the module Jnius is not found.
I have pyjnius installed on my dev machine and this shows in visual studio codes interpreter and the like.
I have tried doing a pip install in the build.gradle but android studio wont install jnius that way (however it works perfectly for the openai library).

e.g.

```
python{
            pip{
                install "jnius"
            }
        }
```

In my script.py in src/main/python I have this for my imports:

```
from jnius import autoclass
import openai
```

Am I simply using Jnius(pyjnius) incorrectly? Or is it not compatible for use with chaquopy/android studio?

[error as seen in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zptU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyjnius is not compatible with Chaquopy. You should use [Chaquopy's own API](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/python.html) instead.

For simple cases, you may be able to simply replace `from jnius import autoclass` with `from java import jclass as autoclass`.